# Multi Input Bidirectional RNN Error Value Error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

So i have built a Multi Input model with a concatenation, and i am getting a value error. i'll reference all these below.

```
def bidir_model(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, meta, vocabulary_size, output):
    nlp_input = Input(shape=(388,), name='nlp_input')
    meta_input = Input(shape=(2,), name='meta_input')
    emb = Embedding(output_dim=vocabulary_size, input_dim=100, input_length=388)(nlp_input)
    nlp_out = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3, 
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))(emb)
    x = concatenate([nlp_out, meta_input])
    x = Dense(150, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(output, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=[nlp_input , meta_input], outputs=[x])
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
    ckpnt = ModelCheckpoint('model_bidir.h5', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)
    model.fit([x_train, meta], y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), batch_size=150, epochs=10, callbacks=[ckpnt])
```

my nlp input is a sequence built with tokenizer.text_to_sequences() and also padded with zeros.
and the meta_input is an array with all my numerical features, i am getting this error...

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[    0,     0,     0, ...,   139,   105,   478],
>          [    0,     0,     0, ...,   112,  3247, 21827],
>          [    0,     0,     0, ...,    91, 65372,    72],
>          ...,
>          [    0,     ...

They are all numpy arrays for sure. Thanks in advance :)!

Comment: Which line gives you this error? Can you post the shape and type of the input array for the function which gives the error ??

Comment: x_train shape --> (1074827, 388)
meta shape --> (1074827, 2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modeling_processes.py", line 122, in <module>
    bidir_model(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test, meta=x_num, vocabulary_size=vocabulary_size, output=labels.shape[1])
  File "C:\Users\Nickos\Desktop\project_categorization\bidir_model.py", line 29, in bidir_model
    model.fit([x_train,meta], y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), batch_size=150, epochs=10, callbacks=[ckpnt])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `validation_data` is missing values for `meta_input`.

Comment: you are very right sir! i really feel stupid right now, thanks!